# jQuery append element to array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a simple jQuery mp3 player I have a button to load some files

```
  <button type="button" class="nes-btn is-primary" onclick="chooseMusic()">Add</button>
```

The relevant jQuery functions are the following

```
let songData = {
  path: [],
  title: []
};
let audioPlayer = $("audio").get(0);
let playing = false;
let currentIndex = 0;
let timer = null;

function chooseMusic() {
  $("input").click();
}

function musicSelected() {
  let files = $("input").get(0).files;
  console.log(files);

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let {path} = files[i];
    mm.parseFile(path, {
      native: true
    }).then(metadata => {
      songData.path[i] = path;
      songData.title[i] = metadata.common.title;

      let songRow = `
            <tr ondblclick="playSong(${i})">
                <td>${metadata.common.title}</td>
                <td>${metadata.common.artist}</td>
                <td>${secondsToTime(metadata.format.duration)}</td>
            </tr>
            `;

      $("#table-body").append(songRow);
    });
  }
}
```

Now if I add more songs after the initial adding operation, they all show fine in the html table but the array which holds the path information for the file to load gets overwritten.

In the below example you can see the console outputs 3 different adding operations:

```
0: File {name: "03 Take My Hand (Freddy@Disco Radio Edit).mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/03 Take My Hand (Freddy@Disco Radio Edit).mp3", lastModified: 1573134194616, lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 07 2019 14:43:14 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
1: File {name: "01 Almeno stavolta.mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/01 Almeno stavolta.mp3", lastModified: 1573134333350, lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 07 2019 14:45:33 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
2: File {name: "01 Dancing Is Like Heaven (Single Mix) [feat. Yas].mp3", path: ".david/musik/…ncing Is Like Heaven (Single Mix) [feat. Yas].mp3", lastModified: 1573134290426, lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 07 2019 14:44:50 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
3: File {name: "08 Take My Hand (DJ Maraach Remix).mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/08 Take My Hand (DJ Maraach Remix).mp3", lastModified: 1573134220015, lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 07 2019 14:43:40 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
length: 4
__proto__: FileList
29
index.js:102 tick
index.js:18 
FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}
0: File {name: "01 Carry You.m4a", path: ".david/musik/mp3/01 Carry You.m4a", lastModified: 1573133939823, lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 07 2019 14:38:59 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
1: File {name: "05 Mercury May.mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/05 Mercury May.mp3", lastModified: 1573133848536, lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 07 2019 14:37:28 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
length: 2
__proto__: FileList
231
index.js:102 tick
index.js:67 0
42
index.js:102 tick
index.js:67 1
935
index.js:102 tick
index.js:18 
FileList {0: File, 1: File, 2: File, 3: File, 4: File, 5: File, length: 6}
0: File {name: "01 Mad About You.mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/01 Mad About You.mp3", lastModified: 1572570292000, lastModifiedDate: Fri Nov 01 2019 02:04:52 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
1: File {name: "04 Sit and Wait.mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/04 Sit and Wait.mp3", lastModified: 1572570182000, lastModifiedDate: Fri Nov 01 2019 02:03:02 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
2: File {name: "01 Wavin' Flag (Coca-Cola Celebration Mix).mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/01 Wavin' Flag (Coca-Cola Celebration Mix).mp3", lastModified: 1572487402000, lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 31 2019 03:03:22 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
3: File {name: "05 Land of Dreaming.mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/05 Land of Dreaming.mp3", lastModified: 1572487316000, lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 31 2019 03:01:56 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
4: File {name: "02 Solo.mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/02 Solo.mp3", lastModified: 1572487132000, lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 31 2019 02:58:52 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
5: File {name: "10 Postcards.mp3", path: ".david/musik/mp3/10 Postcards.mp3", lastModified: 1572486513000, lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 31 2019 02:48:33 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
length: 6
__proto__: FileList
```

Now, if I click for example to "take my hand" (the first file I added) it will in stead play "Mad about you" because it took over position 0 of the array.

So how can I change my jQuery function to ensure that when I add new files it would add them to the same array without overwriting the key ?

Comment: Please, provide an implementation of `playSong ` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you change your code a bit.

Instead of having an object with two arrays like this:

```
let songData = {
  path: [],
  title: []
};
```

you should have one array of objects like this

```
let songData = [
  { path: 'Path-1', title: 'Title 1'}, 
  { path: 'Path-2', title: 'Title 3'}, 
  { ... }
];
```

Then when you add new elements, you simply need to `push()` the new objects to the array

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  // ...
  let obj = { 'path' : path, 'title' : metadata.common.title };
  songData.push(obj); // this will add it at the end of the array (like append does for a jQuery element)
  // ...
}
```

This way, all the information is stored in the same object and not two different arrays. This also reduces the chances of errors if the indexes are no longer synchronized. Also, it would make it a lot easier to remove elements or switch them around if you ever need to do that.

EDIT AFTER READING THE COMMENTS

So to access your new values, you would need to use the object notation syntax.

```
songData[0].path;
songData[0].title;
```

Where `[0]` is your index.

Example:

```
function playSong(index){
  console.log(songData[index].path);
  console.log(songData[index].title);
}
```

Just make sure you pass the index on double click (0, 1, 2, 3, ect);

`playSong(${i})` should be equal to `playSong(0)` for the first element.

---

If you insist on keeping your current code, the problem with it is that you overwrite the indexes when you import new files

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  //...
  songData.path[i] = path;
  songData.title[i] = metadata.common.title;
```

Here the `[i]` will overwrite every time you add files because it will always be 0, 1, 2... next time you import, it will again be 0, 1, etc.

In order to fix that, just add the item at the end of the array using `.push()`

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  //...
  songData.path.push(path);
  songData.title.push(metadata.common.title);
  //...
```

Comment: I would like to use your first idea and modify the script with an array of objects. I am just getting confused on how to implement that in the play function function playSong(index) {

  //audioPlayer.src = songData.path[index];
console.log(songData[{path: index}]);  // This now returns undefined :(

Comment: second method works but on double click on the song list is still out of sync (  <tr ondblclick="playSong(${i})">

Comment: @devnull to access it, you need to access the object using object notation. Something like this songData[0].path and songData[0].title. You can change [0] to the index you need.